# What is best way to create an array of hashes from an array?

Tags: ruby

Given this array:

```
array = ['one', 'two']
```

what is the best way to turn that into something like the following?

```
[{value: 'one', label: 'one'}, {value: 'two', label: 'two'}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Array#map`, which iterates over your collection and returns an array. In your case, just return the hash directly

```
array.map { |a| {value: a, label: a} }
# => [{:value=>"one", :label=>"one"}, {:value=>"two", :label=>"two"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is `Array#map`, but just to try a different way check also [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
array = ['one', 'two']
array.each_with_object([]) { |e, a| a << {value: e, label: e} }
#=> [{:value=>"one", :label=>"one"}, {:value=>"two", :label=>"two"}]
```